# React Native Paper - TextInput outlined iOS weird shadows

Tags: ios, react-native, shadow, textinput, react-native-paper

I'm having issue with a weird shadows in the TextInput component. 
The same app/code runs absolutely fine on android. 
I've tried messing around with styling but didn't get anywhere, when I change to `mode: "flat"` it works fine but I wanted to use `outlined` instead.
Here is a code I'm using, nothing fancy and also the result is the same on the default theme.

```
        <View style={styles.maniView}>
        <Appbar.Header>
            <Appbar.BackAction onPress={() => { navigation.goBack() }} />
            <Appbar.Content title="Add New Device" />
        </Appbar.Header>
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <View><Text style={styles.text}>To add new device enter device key in box below and press <Text style={styles.textBold}>Add Device</Text> button.</Text></View>
                <TextInput
                    mode='outlined'
                    label="Device Key"
                    style={styles.inputField}
                    onChangeText={onNewDeviceKeyChanged}
                    value={newDeviceKey}
                    placeholder="Enter device key"
                    right={newDeviceKey ? <TextInput.Icon icon="close-circle" onPress={cleanDeviceKey} /> : null}
                    returnKeyType={"next"}
                    error={!!errorMsg.length}
                />

                <HelperText style={styles.mainErrorMsg} type="error" visible={!!errorMsg.length}>
                    {errorMsg.length &&
                        <>
                            {`${errorMsg}, Please try again.`}
                        </>
                    }
                </HelperText>

                <Button loading={loading} icon={"plus"} style={styles.addButtonNew} disabled={addNewDeviceDisabled()} mode="contained" onPress={addDevice}>
                    {loading ? "Loading..." : "Add Device"}
                </Button>
            </View>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

    </View>
```

Modules version:

```
"react-native-paper": "^5.7.0",
"react-native": "^0.71.7",
"react": "18.2.0",
```

Any help welcomed.

[image]
[image]